# Simple bounding question for an expectation with truncating function

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $\{X_m\}$ be independent random sequence. I want to show the following result

> Given $E[X_m^2]:=\sigma^2 < \infty$ and 
>   $$0 = \mathop {\sup }\limits_m P\left( {\left| {{X_m}} \right| > C } \right) $$ for some constant $C>0$.
>   Then
>   for any $\varepsilon>0$,
>   $$\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{m = 1}^n {E[{X_m}^2 \cdot {1_{\left\{ {\left| {{X_m}} \right| > \sqrt n \varepsilon } \right\}}}]}  \to 0 \text{ as $n \to \infty$} \;\;\;\; (*)$$

Here is my try: Fix $n$ and take $C:=\sqrt{n}\varepsilon$, then I have
$$0 = \mathop {\sup }\limits_m P\left( {\left| {{X_m}} \right| > \sqrt n \varepsilon } \right) = \mathop {\sup }\limits_m E\left[ {{1_{\left\{ {\left| {{X_m}} \right| > \sqrt n \varepsilon } \right\}}}} \right]$$
then if I able to separate the two terms in $(*)$ then I win; however, I can't do that successfully since the independence cannot apply here. I was wondering is there any clever way to bound ${E[{X_m}^2 \cdot {1_{\left\{ {\left| {{X_m}} \right| > \sqrt n \varepsilon } \right\}}}]}$ so that I can say it indeed vanishes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For fixed $\varepsilon>0$, we can choose $N$ sufficiently large such that $\sqrt{N} \varepsilon>C$. Then

$$\mathbb{P}(|X_m|>\sqrt{n} \varepsilon) = 0$$

implies

$$\mathbb{E}(X_m^2 1_{\{|X_m|>\sqrt{n} \varepsilon\}})=0$$

for all $n \geq N$. Writing

$$\begin{align*} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{m=1}^N\mathbb{E}(X_m^2 1_{\{|X_m|>\sqrt{n} \varepsilon\}}) &= \frac{1}{n} \sum_{m=1}^N \mathbb{E}(X_m^2 1_{\{|X_m|>\sqrt{n} \varepsilon\}})+ \frac{1}{n} \sum_{m=N+1}^n \underbrace{\mathbb{E}(X_m^2 1_{\{|X_m|>\sqrt{n} \varepsilon\}})}_{0} \\ &\stackrel{n \to \infty}{\to} 0. \end{align*}$$